# Code First - persisting an object without specialized DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Code First is a terrific feature. But I could not figure out how to persist an object without creating a specialized DbContext first. Is it possible at all? I'd like to see something along these lines:

```
        var dbConn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=Test.sdf");
        using (var db = new DbContext(dbConn, true))
        {
            var cmp = new Company { CompanyName = "Microsoft" };
            db.Set(typeof(Company)).Add(cmp);
            var recordsAffected = db.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine(
                "Saved {0} entities to the database, press any key to exit.",
                recordsAffected);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Is it possible to dynamically register a class for model creation? There must be a way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as I know there is not any possibility to create `DbContext` without any information about mapping. Specialized context with predefined DbSets is necessary to define mappings and database initialization. You can probably use base DbContext only if you provide informations about mapping through its constructor by passing `DbCompiledModel` created manually before using `DbContext` but I haven't tried this yet.

The problem is that DbSets and overriden `OnModelCreating` are used to infer needed mapping. If you don't have DbSets or `OnModelCreating` defined `DbContext` can't infer and cache mapping. Mapping metadata are created and compiled only once for each context type (until application restarts). This operation is considered as very slow. If you don't have specific context type EF can't probably infer mapping and even if it can it will probably need to create and compile metadata for each instance of the context (like for anonymous types).

If you use `DbCompiledModel` created manually it will be your responsibility to reuse it.